# Can string be passed as data in setting the http method in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am working on Xcode 7.2 and swift 2.0 and I'm converting a block of Objective-C code to swift . The Code in Objective-c is

```
  NSString *jsonstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[requests setHTTPBody:[jsonstring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I am passing the urlData as a parameter while calling the function. this works fine in obj-c .. But when I convert this into swift 2.0 as

```
let jsonstring = String(data: urlData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
requests.HTTPBody = String(data: jsonstring, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

error is shown in this line as

> "cannot convert value of type 'string' to expected argument type
>   nsdata"

Can anyone help in telling me why is this error being thrown and what should I do to rectify the code ?

Answer (score 0):

`[jsonstring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];` is the method `-[NSString dataUsingEncoding:]`.

`String(data: jsonstring, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)` is the method `-[NSString initWithData:encoding:]`.

This is not equivalent code. Try calling `jsonstring.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)` instead.